# What kind of mathematics is this?

Tags: game-theory

Little backstory, I basically taught myself Algebra I and II and some trigonometry using textbook self-study and some YouTube resources. But I'm trying to get into some more advanced stuff related to game theory, and there is math accompanying it that I have never seen before.

What sort of 'course of study' should I pursue before attempting to follow the math below?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqohe.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV5jQ.png)
[Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zP24.png)

Comment: Probability, mostly.

Comment: Also, some linear algebra (algebra with vectors and matrices) can be handy..